# Fail to add new record on nHibernate many to one mapping

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-one

```
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Source Error: 
Line 33:             ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();
Line 34:             session.SaveOrUpdate(productX);
Line 35:             tx.Commit();
Line 36:         }
Line 37: 

Source File: ProductService.cs    Line: 35 

Stack Trace: 
[SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.]

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Aquamate.DataObjects.Core" assembly="Aquamate.DataObjects.Core">
    <class name="Product" table="revProduct">
        <id name="Pid" >
            <generator class="guid.comb" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="ProductCategory" class="Category" lazy="proxy">
            <column name="Catid" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="NameEng" not-null="true" />
        <property name="NameTch" not-null="true" />
        <property name="Status" not-null="true" />
        <property name="Sort" not-null="true" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

What this error usually means is that you are trying to insert a value to a database column where the size of the data is bigger than what is defined for the column.

Check the size defined in the database for all the mapped properties and compare it with the data you are trying to insert.

NHIbernate Profiler can be your best friend here